Raspberry pi nginx PHP execute shell command
I am trying to execute this code with nginx/php 7.3 / wordpress site on my raspberry pi
<?php
   $output = shell_exec('v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --list-formats-ext');
   echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>

The problem is I get no answer If its called from wordpress site. If I manually run shell command
pi@localhost:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/RPi/View/main_part $ php 1.php

It works fine.
If I remove "-d /dev/video0 --list-formats-ext" and leave only v4l2-ctlit
<?php
   $output = shell_exec('v4l2-ctl');
   echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>

I get the correct answer on wordpress site (General/Common options list).
Any suggestions what am I doing wrong?

Probably a permission issue. The user that PHP runs under can't access /dev/video0.

Yes You are right "sudo usermod -a -G video www-data" made it work
